# Unable to execute HTTP request - DynamoDB Local Maven Dependency

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html) of Dynamo DB, we can install DynamoDB locally via Maven dependency as well. Just need to include the dependency and repository in the POM File.
Use case: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=180367

So, I have written a code in Java which just creates a table and I have included the DynamoDBLocal dependency in the pom file as well.

Java Code:

```
public void createTable(String tableName) {

        CreateTableRequest request = new CreateTableRequest()
                .withAttributeDefinitions(new AttributeDefinition(
                        "Name", ScalarAttributeType.S))
                .withKeySchema(new KeySchemaElement("Name", KeyType.HASH))
                .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(
                        10L, 10L))
                .withTableName(tableName);

        final AmazonDynamoDB ddb = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "us-west-2"))
                .build();

        try {
            CreateTableResult result = ddb.createTable(request);
            System.out.println(result.getTableDescription().getTableName());
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
            <version>[1.12,2.0)</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!--Custom repository:-->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dynamodb-local-oregon</id>
            <name>DynamoDB Local Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

I am getting the following error, while running the code. Can somebody help me out here?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost:8000 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:6164)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:6131)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeCreateTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1154)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.createTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1119)
    at DynamoDB.createTable(DynamoDB.java:30)
    at main.main(main.java:4)
```

Comment: Were you ever able to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add this plugin config.
   This is for copying the binary libs to your target dir.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>dynamodb-local</id>
        <name>DynamoDB Local Release Repository</name>
        <url>https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeScope>test</includeScope>
                        <includeTypes>so,dll,dylib</includeTypes>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/native-libs</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <sqlite4java.library.path>${project.build.directory}/native-libs</sqlite4java.library.path>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

2. Create server before creating a table.
   Your local dynamoDB server must be running before you start submitting requests. If you are not doing this, this might explain why you are getting `connection refused`.
   You can copy the [rule for creating server from here](https://github.com/bhdrkn/Java-Examples/blob/master/aws-dynamodb-tutorial/src/test/java/com/bahadirakin/dynamodb/rules/LocalDynamoDBCreationRule.java)
   Once you have the above class you just need to add this member variable to your tests.

   @ClassRule
   static final LocalDynamoDBCreationRule server = new LocalDynamoDBCreationRule ();  This makes sure that you have a running server before you start running your tests.